# Unable to call the repaint in applet from child frame

Tags: java, events, applet, awt

I have made an applet name ParentApplet.java whose task is to create a child frame
Child frame coding is defined in ChildFrame.java

ParentApplet.java

```
public class ParentApplet extends Applet {

ChildFrame frame;
private static int time = 0;

@Override
public void start() {
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    frame.setVisible(false);
}

@Override
public void init() {

    frame = new ChildFrame("Child");
    this.setSize(400, 400);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString("Child's Info : " + (++time), 50, 100);
    g.drawString(frame.getMessage(), 400, 100);
    System.out.println(frame.getMessage().isEmpty() ? "Empty" : frame.getMessage());
}
```

}

ChildFrame.java

public class ChildFrame extends Frame {

```
private String mess = "";

public ChildFrame(String title) {
    super(title);
    addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter(this));
    addWindowListener(new MyWindowAdapter(this));
    setSize(300, 500);
}

public String getMessage() {
    return mess;
}

public void setMessage(String mess) {
    this.mess = mess;
    (new ParentApplet()).repaint();
    System.out.println("Click");
}
```

}

MyMouseAdapter.java

public class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

```
ChildFrame frame;

public MyMouseAdapter(ChildFrame frame) {
    this.frame = frame;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    frame.setMessage("Mouse Cliked in Child");  
}
```

}

MyWindowAdapter.java

public class MyWindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter {

```
ChildFrame frame;

public MyWindowAdapter(ChildFrame frame) {
    this.frame = frame;
}

@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
    frame.setVisible(false);
}
```

}

Now i am unable to reach the paint method again even after calling the repaint method from the ChildFrame class. Please suggest me whether i have done something wrong or some thing i need to understand.

Thanks in advance
Gagandeep Singh

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is basically "you don't do that".

The Applet's paint() method is responsible for painting the contents of the actual applet component-- i.e. the visible component that appears in the web page. Your ChildFrame should then have a separate paint() method to paint itself (or in fact, would usually have a Canvas added to it, and that Canvas in turn has its own paint() method).

(Remember that in Java a "Frame" is effectively a "window"-- i.e. a standalone window that opens separately to the web page.)

You can call repaint() on whatever component from wherever you like. This will eventually lead to that component's paint() method being called. In your particular example, you shouldn't call "new ParentApplet()" -- you don't want to call repaint() on some randomly created new applet, but rather on the single already existing one. So change this by passing a reference to your applet into the constructor of ChildFrame which ChildFrame can then hold as an instance variable and re-use when needed:

```
public class ChildFrame extends Frame {

  private String mess = "";
  private final ParentApplet parentApplet;

  public ChildFrame(ParentApplet applet, String title) {
    super(title);
    this.parentApplet = applet;
    addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter(this));
    addWindowListener(new MyWindowAdapter(this));
    setSize(300, 500);
  }
  ...
  public void setMessage(String mess) {
    this.mess = mess;
    parentApplet.repaint();
  }
}
```

I must admit that so far, it's not immediately obvious why you would have a setMessage() on a separate frame whose purpose is to set the message displayed in the applet. Why not put the setMessage() method on the applet in that case? But maybe you have another reason for doing it your way that isn't apparent so far.

Comment: So u want to say, there's no way to paint the parent applet from child frame ?

Comment: Not directly, but it's not clear why you would want to do that anyway? Why not just put the applet's painting code where it belongs: in the applet's paint() method?

Comment: I have done that only, it's just the thing that i am calling the repaint method of applet from child frame class.(new ParentApplet()).repaint(); This is the code from child frame calling ParentApplet's paint method

Comment: OK, have updated my answer. Basically, you can call repaint() on whatever component you want whenever you want. But you need to make sure you're calling it on the right component. You were trying to create a *new* applet object, whereas what you need to do is call repaint() on the existing one.

Comment: Aaah silly indeed very silly from my side. I got lost in understanding the awt, event and applets that i missed such a simple point. Thanks to you very much it did solved my problem. :-)